# How to Execute Script Instead of Reading from File?

Tags: files, scripting

Is it possible to set up a file such that when it is referenced (opened for read), the contents of the file are not returned but instead the results of running a script or executable?

I realise that this can be done from the command line with stdout and pipes, but it's not always the case that I need to reference a script from the command line.

Comment: This question has the signs of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you provide an example or details that describe what problem this feature is supposed to solve? An alternative approach, and a common pattern in Unix & Linux would be to structure the script to read input from `stdin`, and use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to direct output from a produced script to the `stdin` of the consumer script: `consumer.sh <(producer.sh)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly do this. What you can do is (as you say) to use *stdout* and pipes. Not ideal, and not particularly elegant, so you probably ought to rethink your requirement and proposed solution.

Let's assume the file in question is to be called `date`, and you want it to print a message about the current date/time:

```
# Create the "file" as a FIFO (a pipe)
mkfifo date

# Start the background process that always ensures there's data in the FIFO
( while :; do ( echo "The current date/time is $(date)" ) >date; done ) &

# Now read the "file" that's actually a pipe
date        # Date/time now
cat date    # Content from the "file" that's actually a pipe
date        # Date/time now, again

# And a minute or so later, try that again, just to show the effect of a
# repeated read...
cat date
```